# Tell search engine not to follow the links

Tags: seo, search-engine

I just need clarification about:

```
<meta name="robots" content="nofollow"/>
```

It is clear that By including this in head content at page level will tell search engine not to follow the links which are in this page.

Now, will it also include the page in the "nofollow" zone in which this is written?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To exclude the page from search engine index where you have written:

```
 <meta name="robots" content="nofollow"/>
```

You also need to add the **noindex** directive to hint search engine bots NOT to index the page like this:

```
<meta name="robots" content="nofollow,noindex"/>
```

To make it further clear, there are four implementations of the Robots meta tags for search engine bots:

**1.**

```
 <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

This simply means: "Do not index this page and do not follow the links on the page." So, your page will drop out of the search engine index and your external links on the page will not be followed (link juice will NOT be transferred).

**2.**

```
  <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="INDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

This simply means: "Do index this page but do not follow the links on the page." So, your page will get indexed by search engines and your external links present on the page will not be followed (link juice will NOT be transferred).

**3.**

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, FOLLOW">
```

This simply means: "Do not index this page and do follow the links on the page." So, your page will drop out of the search engine index but your external links present on the page will be followed (link juice will be transferred to external links).

**4.**

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="INDEX, FOLLOW">
```

This simply means: "Do index this page and do follow the external links on the page." So, your page will be included in the search engine index and your external links present on the page will be followed (link juice will be transferred).

Comment: thanks for such a nice explanation, but I need to ask one more thing that if I include <meta name="robots" content="nofollow"/> in a submaster page then will it also include the links of master page??

Comment: http://example.com/master-page/sub-master-page and http://example.com/master-page/ are two different URLs therefore no-following links on one page will not effect the links on the other page. 

You will have to include the meta tags on both the pages separately to make external links no-follow on both the pages.

Answer (score 2):

The meta tag **nofollow** is just for the links in the page. 
To include the page where is written you have to include `noindex` and `noarchive` tag.

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,noarchive,nofollow"/>
```